# how to change prompt in terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I want to change my username view from `[sdevraj@inn-sdevraj-vm ~/Dir1]` to this `sdevraj@inn-sdevraj-vm` and vice-versa. Basically, I want to remove directory name which comes inside [].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enter in your `~./bashrc` file and change:

```bash
export PS1=""\u@\h> "
```

`\h` is a variable representing the hostname, `\u`is a variable representing the current logged-in user. More details [here](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-prompt.html).

A random Google search shows [this tool](http://bashrcgenerator.com/) to create a PS1 prompt with drag and drop.

Update the changes using `source ~./bashrc`.